# Populate one path of an object nested inside array for specific fileds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My Posts Schema has a "comments" array path, for each "comment", "user" is objectId to User Modal. How could I populate only "name", "_id", "thumbnailURI" for the user.

what the posts db looks like:

```
[
...
  {
        "_id": "5ce5b41222fa4937f8a495e5",
        "owner": "5ce5b41123456789f8a495e5",
        "uri": "uri.jpg",
        "comments": [
            {
                "date": "2019-05-23T23:24:47.554Z",
                "_id": "5ce72bbf88781b35fca696ce",
                "user": "5cdda3a4f5a8a077a9352f38",
                "content": "cute!!!"
            },
            {
                "date": "2019-05-23T23:28:52.941Z",
                "_id": "5ce72cb46fba6f1bece267db",
                "user": "5cdda3a4f5a8a077a9352f38",
                "content": "cute!!!"
            }
        ],
        "createAt": "2019-05-22T20:41:54.290Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
...
]
```

I want the "comments" looks like this:

```
"comments": [
            {
                "date": "2019-05-23T23:24:47.554Z",
                "_id": "5ce72bbf88781b35fca696ce",
                "user": {
                      "name": "name",
                      "_id": "5ce72cb46fb5ce72cb46fb"
                      "thumbnailURI": "thumbnailURI.jpg"
                 },
                "content": "cute!!!"
            },
            {
                "date": "2019-05-23T23:28:52.941Z",
                "_id": "5ce72cb46fba6f1bece267db",
                "user": {
                      "name": "name",
                      "_id": "5ce72cb46fb5ce72cb46fb"
                      "thumbnailURI": "thumbnailURI.jpg"
                 },
                "content": "cute!!!"
            }
        ],
```

Tried

```
posts
                .getByOwners(owners)
                .populate('owner', 'username thumbnail _id')
                .populate({
                    path: "comments",
                    populate: {
                        path: "user",
                        model: "user",
                    }
                });
```

get empty "comments" array
Thank you!

Comment: can you update the question with user and comment model? just to check!

Comment: path should be `path: "comments.user"`. If your Ids wrapped with `ObjectId`.

Comment: @the_mahasagar Thank you for your reply. I only have a user model with some paths, but don't have a comment model.

Comment: @Fanpark Thank you for your reply. I tried, but didn't work. "user" path belongs to one object inside "comments" array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advises.

1. I have a "user" model with some paths
2. There is no "comments" model. "comments" is an array embedded in "post" model.

The query looks like this:

```
posts
.findById(id)
.populate('owner', 'username thumbnail _id')
.populate("comments.user", 'username thumbnail _id')
```

This is the final result I want:

```
"comments": [
            {
                "date": "2019-05-23T23:24:47.554Z",
                "_id": "5ce72bbf88781b35fca696ce",
                "user": {
                    "thumbnail": "pic1.jpg",
                    "_id": "5cdda3a4f5a8a077a9352f38",
                    "username": "a"
                },
                "content": "cute!!!"
            },
            {
                "date": "2019-05-23T23:28:52.941Z",
                "_id": "5ce72cb46fba6f1bece267db",
                "user": {
                    "thumbnail": "pic2.jpg",
                    "_id": "5cdda3a4f5a8a077a9352f38",
                    "username": "a"
                },
                "content": "cute!!!"
            }
],
```